# View getting pushed to right of screen for bigger screens

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I am working on an Ionic Application where for normal sized screens i.e. most smartphones, smaller tablets the view looks perfect (well centered)[image: perfect image]

However once the screen size gets bigger (large ipad) the view seems to stick to the right [image: imperfect image]

In the image you can see the space on the left. 
In my `index.html` where this view enters from I'm using a simple `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`and my main html file has a simple format of

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-pane>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
 </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

The main thing to note is that this shifting to the right happens for all pages in the App for large screens only.
Anyone know the solution please?

**Update**: Seems to be happening on a few large screen devices, not all large screen devices, one such device in question is an Ipad Mini 1st Gen 9.3.5

My `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>XX</title>

    <link href="css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- compiled css output -->
    <link href="css/hint.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/collide.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.tdcards.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just cut out that part, move it slightly to the left and past it back in again...and if you need help with code, we need to see that as well :)

Comment: Added index.html, because of confidentiality I can't share all the code